# Setting option in ascx select structure causes overflow exception

Tags: c#, set, postback

I have defined in an *.ascx control a select structure like so:

**MyList.ascx**

```
<%@Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyList.ascx.cs" Inherits = "myProj.Views.Shared.MyList"%>
<select id="listSelector" name="properties" onchange="listSelectChange()">
     <option value="First Name" selected="selected"> First Name </option>
     <option value="Last Name"> Last Name </option>
     <option value="Age"> Age </option>
</select>
<script type='text/javascript">
     alert("HI");
</script>
```

**MyList.ascx.cs**

```
 public partial class listSelector: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchProperty"] != null)
            {
                string lastIndex = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchProperty"].ToString();
                this.SelectedValue = lastIndex;
            }

        }
    }

    private string SelectedValue
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.SelectedValue; 
        }
        set 
        {
            this.SelectedValue = value; 
        }
    }
}//end of class
```

**MyView.aspx**

```
  <%@ Register TagPrefix="PropertyDropDownList" TagName="ListSelector" Src="~/Views/Shared/ListSelector.ascx" %>
  .... 
  <PropertyDropDownList:ListSelector runat="server" ID="ListSelect" />
```

*Question*
When I assign the selected value in the Page_Load-> IF block; I get to the setter and then get an overflow exception, No inner details, just that there's a System.OverflowException. What am I over looking here? is there a way to set the ASCX option from the code behind to avoid loosing the value last selected on a post back?

Comment: You get an error because your property `SelectedValue` calls itself, and then calls itself and then itself until you go too deep down the stack

Comment: i realize that's what's causing the exception, I guess I should have asked how to set the value of the contrl without getting that exception

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

**ASCX:**

```
    <%@Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyList.ascx.cs" Inherits = "myProj.Views.Shared.MyList"%>
    <asp:DropDownList id="listSelector" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Selected="true">First Name </asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem> Last Name </asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem> Age </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
enter code here
    public partial class listSelector: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchProperty"] != null)
            {
                string lastIndex = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchProperty"].ToString();
                listSelector.SelectedValue = lastIndex;
            }

        }
    }

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get 
        {
            return listSelector.SelectedValue;
        }
        set 
        {
            listSelector.SelectedValue = value; 
        }
    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've implemented your second approach and that fixed the overflow exception but I'm still seeing the default value set for the control...

Comment: Where are you seeing it set to the default?  The code you provided only shows you assigning it a value.  Also you probably want the property to be public instead of private if you intend to access the value from a page's code behind.

Comment: In MyView.aspx, I have a button that calls the controller, when the controller executes, it returns a list of results through a post back call. when the results come back, I'm seeing the first element in in my list displayed

Comment: also, the ViewState has no enumerated results when I'm debugging, is there some way I'm suppose to set that up ahead of time?

Comment: See my edited answer above.  I suspect this is what you are really trying to do.  Your original ascx had an html list, instead of an asp.net control, so you couldn't access the values from your code behind.